# Android notifyDataSetChanged not updating view on existing items?

Tags: java, android, adapter

New to android and having a hard time figuring out why **notifyDataSetChanged();** isn't updating items that were removed from view when reinserting them. Working great when deleting items but not when restoring items back to view which were existing items in view. Any help is appreciated.

**UsersAdapter.java**

```
public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.UserViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<User> mDataSet;
private Context context;

private SQLiteDatabase db;

public UsersAdapter(ArrayList<User> mDataSet, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mDataSet = mDataSet;

    createDatabase();

}

public void createDatabase(){
    db=context.openOrCreateDatabase("xxx", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS faces(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR,url VARCHAR);");
}


@Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_favorites2, parent, false);
    UserViewHolder userViewHolder = new UserViewHolder(v);
    return userViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {


    holder.name_entry.setText(mDataSet.get(position).getName());
    holder.email_entry.setText(mDataSet.get(position).getEmail());
    holder.icon_entry.setText(""+mDataSet.get(position).getName().charAt(0));

    String name = mDataSet.get(position).getName();
    String url = mDataSet.get(position).getEmail();

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .asBitmap()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_blank)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_blank)
            .into(holder.ivFavorites);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSet.size();
}

public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cardView;
    TextView name_entry, email_entry, icon_entry;
    ImageView ivFavorites;

    UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_layout);
        name_entry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_entry);
        email_entry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.email_entry);
        icon_entry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_entry);
        ivFavorites = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivFavorites);

        Typeface fontFamily2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
        TextView fontFamilyText2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fontAwesomeDirectLink);
        fontFamilyText2.setTypeface(fontFamily2);
        fontFamilyText2.setText("\uf0c1");
        fontFamilyText2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.bg_screen3));
        fontFamilyText2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                context = view.getContext();
                final User mDataSet2 = mDataSet.get(getAdapterPosition());;
                String url = mDataSet2.getEmail();
                String name = mDataSet2.getName();
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("xxx direct link", url);
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(view, "Copied " + name + "!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setActionTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_screen3))
                        .setAction("ADD IMG TAGS", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                context = view.getContext();
                                final User mDataSet2 = mDataSet.get(getAdapterPosition());;
                                String url = mDataSet2.getEmail();
                                String name = mDataSet2.getName();
                                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("xxx direct link with image tags", "[img]" + url + "[/img]");
                                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                                Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(view, "Added image tags!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                snackbar1.show();
                            }
                        });

                snackbar.show();
            }
        });

        Typeface fontFamily3 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
        TextView fontFamilyText3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fontAwesomeImageTagLink);
        fontFamilyText3.setTypeface(fontFamily3);
        fontFamilyText3.setText("\uf00d");
        fontFamilyText3.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.dot_dark_screen1));
        fontFamilyText3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                context = view.getContext();
                final User mDataSet3 = mDataSet.get(getAdapterPosition());;
                String url = mDataSet3.getEmail();
                String name = mDataSet3.getName();
                String query = "DELETE FROM faces WHERE url = ('"+url+"');";
                db.execSQL(query);
                mDataSet.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(view, name + " Removed!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setActionTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.dot_dark_screen1))
                        .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                context = view.getContext();
                                final User mDataSet3 = mDataSet.get(getAdapterPosition());;
                                String url = mDataSet3.getEmail();
                                String name = mDataSet3.getName();
                                String query = "INSERT INTO faces (name,url) VALUES('"+name+"', '"+url+"');";
                                db.execSQL(query);
                                Snackbar snackbar3 = Snackbar.make(view, name + " Favorited!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                snackbar3.show();
                            }
                        });
                snackbar.show();
            }
        });


        Typeface fontFamily4 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
        TextView fontFamilyText4 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fontAwesomeShare);
        fontFamilyText4.setTypeface(fontFamily4);
        fontFamilyText4.setText("\uf1e0");
        fontFamilyText4.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.bg_screen3));
        fontFamilyText4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                context = view.getContext();
                final User mDataSet2 = mDataSet.get(getAdapterPosition());;
                String url = mDataSet2.getEmail();
                String name = mDataSet2.getName();
                Drawable mDrawable = ivFavorites.getDrawable();
                Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mDrawable).getBitmap();
                Bitmap imageWithBG = Bitmap.createBitmap(600, 600, mBitmap.getConfig());  // Create another image the same size
                imageWithBG.eraseColor(Color.WHITE);  // set its background to white, or whatever color you want
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(imageWithBG);  // create a canvas to draw on the new image
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 175, 100, null); // draw old image on the background
                String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(),
                        imageWithBG, "xxx", null);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
                final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); // THIS IS SLOW 
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                context.startActivity(shareIntent);
            }
        });

    }
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
}
```

Comment: move all your remove code inside bindviewholder,there you will get position,call notifiydatasetchanged there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Your Snackbar code

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(view, name + " Removed!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setActionTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.dot_dark_screen1))
                        .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                context = view.getContext();
                                final User mDataSet3 = mDataSet.get(getAdapterPosition());;
                                String url = mDataSet3.getEmail();
                                String name = mDataSet3.getName();
                                String query = "INSERT INTO faces (name,url) VALUES('"+name+"', '"+url+"');";
                                db.execSQL(query);
                                mDataSet.add(mDataSet3);
                                 notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Snackbar snackbar3 = Snackbar.make(view, name + " Favorited!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                snackbar3.show();
                            }
                        });
                snackbar.show();
```

Comment: Hey Younas, your suggestion works fine to delete (which was already working fine) but the restore is still not working. If I change activities and come back to my view the view is refreshed and the item is restored. Anyways to restore the item without leaving the activity?

Comment: you mean the deleted item is is not restoring when u click on undo ?

Comment: No, what I mean is the line .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() is not restoring the item back into view. Only if I leave the view and come back I see the item restored.

Comment: did you try  notifyItemInserted(getAdapterPosition());
 notifyDataSetChanged(); in the undo click ?

Comment: Tried both earlier and again now, it doesnt work. I think                                     notifyDataSetChanged(); only restores items back into view IF the item was NOT already in view. Only new items being added or removed work with                                     notifyDataSetChanged(); and not existing items it seem.

Comment: When I click on the UNDO action the snackbar shows, the sqlite data is restored into database but the card doesn't show, only when I leave the activity and come back the card then shows.

Comment: plz check my edit code and than run again i hope it will help  you

Comment: Younas I get "Addall in Arraylist cannot be applied to Com.Com.xxx.User

**User**

Comment: public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name, url;

    public User(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.url = email;
    }
}

Comment: plz add the deleted item to mDataset when you click on undo than it will be notified otheriwise not

Comment: instead of **addAll()** replace with **add()** as i edit the code

Comment: Sorry I'm getting an exception warning with crash  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: I made the changes with the new edits.

Comment: check your code it should not happen because you are just adding the one item in dataset than how this exception happen

Comment: why notifydatasetchanges() not work because you did not adding the deleted item back into mDataset if you do it than it will be notificed

Comment: Code looks good, no errors inside Android studio after adding deleted item back via mDataset and then notifydatasetchanges() the app crashes when click on UNDO.

Comment: I had to remove final User mDataSet3 = mDataSet.get(getAdapterPosition());; and then it works fine, thank you so much Younas for your fantastic assistance. I understand why notifydatasetchanges() now wasnt working, because I wasn't adding the data back before.

Comment: plz vote up for my answer so that it help other its good that you understand the logic

Comment: Thanks any help you need just tag me into the question

Comment: It is my pleasure, thank you for your incredible assistance.